# How to include media (print|screen) on angular-cli.json

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

I want to configure materialize(css) on media=screen and bootstrap(css) on media=print, but I don't know doing it through angular-cli.json. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using a css preprocessor?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not unavailable from angular-cli.json , there is already [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4220) related to this , so basic workaround this is to add the css files to the index.html ,another way is by ussing the css import as an example :

```
@import url("fineprint.css") print;
@import url("bluish.css") speech;
@import 'custom.css';
@import url("chrome://communicator/skin/");
@import "common.css" screen;
@import url('landscape.css') screen and (orientation:landscape);
```

but this give me a diffrent error in angular so my final soultion like this :

```
@media print {
     @import '/assests/print.css';
} 

@media screen {
     @import '/assests/screen.css';  
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-css-media-query)

[MDN @import](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-css-media-query)